# Confusion over arcpy.Describe() properties?

Tags: arcpy

Can someone clarify the meaning of the `'fullPropsRetrieved'`and `'metadataRetrieved'` properties of a [`Describe` object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe-object-properties.htm) within ArcPy.

In particular my confusion is regarding the definitions provided on the ESRI website of each of the properties:

- fullPropsRetrieved: "Indicates whether full properties have been retrieved"
- metadataRetrieved: "Indicates whether the metadata has been retrieved"

What is the difference between these two properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation on these two properties, but this is my *opinion* on what they mean.

Each item returned by `arcpy.Describe()` is called a Property.  The property `fullPropsRetrieved` will be referring to the `Describe` function retrieving the `Describe` properties available for the type of dataset you are describing.

Metadata is data about your data and can be manually populated against a dataset with information about things like copyright, usage, data entry methods, update frequency etc., and are not necessarily items that can be determined just by looking at the type of dataset like a `Describe` does.  The `metadataRetrieved` property likely reports whether the dataset has metadata attached and that `Describe` has been able to access/retrieve that metadata.